# How do make columnname from one table as a tablename in sql join

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

i have 2 tables . column of one table is part of tablename to others , i want to make join in between these tables something like below.

```
      select ar.id,ar.type from Art ar  ,CONCAT('MOK', ar.type) mo where  mo.id= ar.id
```

There is same id present in both table but mo.id does not exist is the exception i m getting.thnx for your time. name of second table is `MOKdance` where `dance =ar.type`

Comment: You are better off changing your table design to avoid such problems

Comment: yes , but i have to use this only for quite some time , it will change in future , plz provide me some solution if there any @juergend

Comment: @Unknown Person - how may different ar.type you have ?

Comment: no don't waste time on this. Get it right.

Comment: @BerndBuffen i have 3 types only